# Cannot import module in Android Studio 0.3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, import-module

I recently updgraded by AS to 0.3.5 and I can't see import module option. When I open

```
ProjectStructure - Modules - Click the + sign
```

I cant see 'Import Module' option. And also I only see "Modules" in Project Settings. [image: Project Structure]

Is there any other way??

Answer (score 1):

This isn't implemented yet for Android Studio; it's being tracked in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62122 . You'll need to move the directory containing the module you want to import under your project root, create a build.gradle file to build it, add an entry to your settings.gradle file to point to it, and re-sync your Android Studio project with Gradle.