# How can include android-bootstrap in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to include the android-bootstrap buttons in android studio, the wiki from github say this:

https://docs.github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap/wiki/Installation-Guide

```
    Please follow these instructions to install the Android Bootstrap library:

Download the project
Unzip the project to somewhere you will remember
Check inside your new folder that you have two projects inside - AndroidBootstrap and AndroidBootstrapTest
Open Eclipse
Press File - Import - Android - Existing Android Code
For the root directory - browse to the location of where the projects are - you'll need to click the top folder to import both the library and the test project
Hopefully you should have two projects to import
Ensure that the "copy projects into workspace" is ticked
Click finish
On the project you want to use AndroidBootstrap - right click - properties
Find the tab on the left that says "Android"
Bottom half of the window is for including libraries - click Add - and select AndroidBootstrap
Should like the image below:
Click Ok
You can now either follow the BootstrapButton guide or FontAwesomeText guide to start adding AndroidBootstrap items in your layouts :)
```

But i dont know how can i do this in android studio..Is my first use with this tool and i am lose..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820723/referencing-existing-library-project-into-main-project/20821772#20821772

Answer (score 1):

**First do not forget to give internet permission to you app add this into your AndroidManifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**put it in Gradle Scripts > build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
implementation 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.3.2
```

Answer (score -1):

create a folder "libs" in the root your project, inside this put AndroidBoostrapsLibrary and add follow code in your setting.grandle

```
':libs:AndroidBootstrap'
```

and  this code

```
compile project(':libs:AndroidBootstrap')
```

in your build.grandle.